# awk command to check whether the SSH connection to peerIP is success

Tags: ssh, awk

The command

```
ssh -q -o "BatchMode=yes" user@host "echo 2>&1" && echo "OK" || echo "NOK"
```

will help in checking whether the SSH connection to peer IP is a success or not.
But I am having only Peer IP so

```
ssh -q -o "BatchMode=yes" peerIP 2>&1" && echo "OK" || echo "NOK"
```

doesnt work.

Anyone knows how can i solve it? A One-liner command is required and it should work on AIX, HP, Linux... any help or suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is the extra quote after 2>&1 a mistake?

Comment: Oh..sorry ..The command should be  ssh -q -o "BatchMode=yes" peerIP "echo 2>&1" && echo "OK" || echo "NOK" but it doesnt work.Do you know any alternative?

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Does it give an error?

Comment: It always gives NOK as result even if SSH connection to peer IP is there.

Comment: Can you "ssh peerIP" and get a shell on the remote system without having to enter a password?

Comment: yes it is possible..i just want a method by ssh to peerIp can be done and get the exit status for the ssh command .It should suppress all the output except for the exit status.Output of the SSH shell command executed should be exit status of the same.Any suggsetions?

Comment: what does this have to do with `awk`, your code is clearly unix shell script. 'Oneliner required' sounds like homework, otherwise why is that critical? Good luck.

Comment: Also, how are you handling the password required by ssh? If your use@host is working without having to type a password, then that means you have a key in your $HOME/.ssh directory. ****ALSO**** noting your most recent response 'I just want a method ... and get the exit status from ssh'. So are you trying to solve why `ssh remHost` (no userID) doesn't work OR are you trying to capture exit code of `ssh`. `ssh .... ; echo $?` will do that. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you mention awk ? 
Whatever, here a solution that works for me:

```
ssh USER@HOST 'env |grep SSH_CLIENT && echo "OK" || echo "NOK"'
```

When SSH is connected to the host, some environment variable will be set.

Also, when your connection to a remote host without using a User in the SSH URL, your current should be set by default. You can change that behavior in your */etc/ssh/ssh_config* .
Maybe that will fix it.

Good luck